# How to run code on last iteration of html5 read file method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this javascript/jquery code I attempt to read multiple files and store them in a dictionary.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    var f, filename;
    for (var i = 0; i<files.length; i++) {
        f = files[i];
        filename = escape(f.name);
        if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function(e) {
                var text = reader.result;
                var arrays = $.csv.toArrays(text);
                frequencies[filename] = arrays;

                generateMenuFromData();
            });

            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsText(f);
        }
    }
}
```

I read only the .csv files. I want to run `generateMenuFromData();` only on the last time the `reader.onload` function runs.

I can't find a good way to do this properly. Does anyone know how?

Thanks.

Comment: Increase a counter inside the event handler. If it is the same the length of the array, execute the function. A more structured approach would be to use promises, but in this simple case it would suffice.

Comment: I was trying that before, but it wasn't working. Can you show how you would do it?

Comment: It's really just adding `1` to a variable and use an `if` statement to compare it. Your problem might have been the closure you create inside the loop. I fixed that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Increase a counter inside the event handler. If it is the same the length of the array, execute the function. A more structured approach would be to use [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), but in this simple case it would suffice:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    var f, filename, loaded = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i<files.length; i++) {
        f = files[i];
        filename = escape(f.name);
        if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) {
            var reader = new FileReader();


            reader.onload = (function(filename, reader) {
                return function(e) {
                    frequencies[filename] =  $.csv.toArrays(reader.result);

                    loaded += 1; // increase counter
                    if (loaded === files.length) {
                       // execute function once all files are loaded
                       generateMenuFromData();
                    }
                };
            }(filename, reader)); // <-- new scope, "capture" variable values

            reader.readAsText(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your real problem might be that you are creating a closure inside the loop. That means when the `load` event handlers are called, `filename` and `reader` will refer to the values the variable had in the *last* iteration of the loop. All handlers share the *same* variables.

See also [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).